# Force app to select sw320dp in android

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

i have created an android app that can work in almost all the devices except resolution of 
320w x 480h (LG-p500) . I tried creating a drawable-sw320dp and also layout-sw320dp.

I also have drawable-mdpi. Right now from LG mobile its selecting mdpi instead of 320dp folder. How do i force my app to pick the the images from sw320 folder, instead of mdpi folder.

Been working on this since two days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of android has it?

Comment: android 2.3.3 is the version.

Answer (score 0):

Change from "drawable-sw320dp" to "drawable-mdpi-sw320dp" and "drawable-mdpi" to "drawable-mdpi-sw321dp"

Comment: Sorry, it should be: drawable-sw320dp-mdpi and drawable-sw321dp-mdpi

Comment: The folder is valid but the image is not picking from the required folder :(

Comment: So blackbelt answer is correct, as Docs says that these qualifiers are avaiable for Android from version 3.2

Comment: so does this mean there is no solution for 2.3.3 Version?

Comment: As I actually now, I'm afraid - yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the device as `Android 2.3.3` all is working as expected. The new qualifiers you want to use, the [smallest-width qualifie](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali)r" have been introduced since `Android 3.2`

Comment: Thanks for the reply...can u let me know what do you mean by "Modifiers"

Comment: I edit my answer. sw360dp is a smallest-width qualifier. Those have been introduce in Android 3.2

Comment: you have to use the old syntax. drawable-mdpi and  layout-mdpi

Answer (score 0):

320dp is the smallest possible width of an Android device, so using -sw320dp qualifier would bring only strange effects and nothing what you want to achieve.

On Android 2.x devices you cannot have such granularity smallest-width brings and you really should not.

**Instead make your layouts elastic.** Difference between `320 x 426 dp`, `320 x 480 dp` and `320 x 533 dp` is not that significant. You can only have -small qualifier for the first (426 dp) device on old Androids.

Comment: are you saying I should just use something that fits on devices 160dpi.

Comment: @DevAndro I don't know what you should. You may want to put layouts and/or graphics you want to use in your case. Normally you don't create layouts for every screen and only choose few groups of devices, e.g. 320-399, 400-479, 480-599, 600-719 and 720+ (5 groups here, but 3 groups work well too in many cases).

Comment: It is just working fine for 400-479, 480-599, 600-719 and 720+. Except for 320-399 - What should be done? :(

Comment: @DevAndro It is impossible to answer without your layout posted.